# When to use t-test for dependent vs. independent sample?

Tags: t-test, sample

I am writing you with a statistics question for which I cannot find an answer on the internet.

I have conducted a survey to find out how much consumers like different products. "Likability" is a 3-item construct in my survey and I test it for 15 different products.

Now I want to know if there is a significant difference in likability between the products. E.g., do consumers like product 1 significantly more than product 2?

To this end, I have calculated a "Likability-Score" for each product which is the mean of all 3 items and all respondents. As far as I understand I now have to run a t-test. But do I have to run a t-test for independent or dependent samples?

From what I read so far: A dependent sample t-test could make sense because respondent may compare likability of different products implicitly. An independent t-test could make sense because there is no before-after assessment with a treatment in between.

Comment: You seem to be saying that you intend to treat the answers a respondent gives for one product as independent of the answers that same respondent gives for the other product.  Is that really plausible?

Comment: I would assume that respondents at least implicitly consider their answer for the last product, when answer the question for the next product.

However, I'm not sure whether this indicates that a dependent sample t-test is appropriate. All examples I found for the dependent sample t-test included a treatment (someone is sick, takes a drug=treatment, and is feeling better)

Comment: The t-test, like most statistical tests, has no knowledge of time nor does it care about it.  The "before-after" business is just a metaphor to help novices grasp the potential applications.  A t-test evaluates the difference of means in two populations or processes of which your two groups are considered random samples. All that matters is whether there is any natural pairing of the two groups that might have a positive correlation.  If so, then the paired t-test will be more powerful (able to distinguish differences) than the unpaired test.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. So in my case, I understand, every product is a group or population. And as responses for different products are dependent, it's best to use the paired t-test.

Comment: @Rike If you read my answer you will see that if you are in the design stage  and you know that the variations within pairs can be reduced by carefully choosing how to pair a paired t test could be better.  I think the daily temperature example is great for understanding the concept. If you have already collected the data and you can't find a sensible way to pair the two independent sample approach may be your only choice.

Comment: Also in your case the t test might not be appropriate at all if the data is not approximately normal.  In that case there are nonparametric analogs to the independent case (Wilcoxon rank sum test) and the paired case (Wilcoxon signed rank test). My example may or may not apply to your situation but I do think it can help you understand how to choose between paired and unpaired tests in other situations.  You wanted an explanation for this that you were unable to find on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My intent with this answer is to show the concepts that indicate that the data is suitable for a paired t test.  There are so many issues that could be discussed about particular data set. This is shown somewhat in the comments above. I address the title question "When to use t test for dependent vs independent sample?" My hope is that my statements and the example will ajavascript:void(0)ddress this issue that the OP could not find on the internet.

First of all to run a two sample t test you need to have incorporated by design a clear correlation between the two variables whose means you want to compare. I will give an example later. If the data is discrete than you want it to be close to continuous and approximately normal. Since the data are paired you want equal sample size.  Now one could reason that "if I run an unpaired t test I don't need equal sample size and I have more degrees on freedom than if I pair" (in the equal sample size case the degrees of freedom for the unpaired t test is 2n-2 compared to n-1 for the paired test).

Although at first blush this seems to automatically favor the independent test to the paired test since more degrees of freedom means a lower variance for the t statistic.  But this is not always so. If the variability between paired differences is much less than the variability within pairs. This is a little vague and you may be puzzled by my terminology.  Here is an example that I hope will make things clear.

Suppose I have average daily temperature data at two locations say Washington DC and New York City. Temperature at a given location is very seasonal and also varies geographically. On a given day New York and Washington DC are geographically close enough to each other to share weather patterns so perhaps the variation in temperature between these two cities on the same day is not as great as the variability when comparing them in different seasons (particularly a winter month vs a summer month). It should be clear that there is a way to pair correlated data from New York and Washington DC.

In a textbook example I used the following sampling to develop a paired t test.  I pair data taken on the same day (15th of the month) for Washington and New York. I collect this data over a given year giving me a sample size of 12 pair.

Here is the data:

Day..............Wash..............NY

....................Avg. Temp.(F)..Avg. Temp.(F)

January...15........31..................28

February..15........35..................33

March......15........40..................37

April.........15........52..................45

May..........15........70..................68

June.........15........76.................74

July...........15........93.................89

August......15........90.................85

September.15........74................69

October......15........55................51

November...15........32................27

December...15........26................24

From this data we get the following set of paired differences 3, 2, 3, 7, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5 and 2

In the book we applied the unpaired test using the pooled estimate of variance and got a test statistic t = 0.378 checking the table with with 22 degrees of freedom we find that this is far from significant.  For alpha =0.10 the critical value is 1.7171 indicating that the p-value is higher than 0.10.

For the paired test we get t=7.86 and referring to a t distribution with 11 degrees of freedom we find that the critical value for alpha = 0.01 is 3.1058. So the p-value is less than 0.01.  In the unpaired case we cannot reject the null hypothesis that the average temperature at New York is different from Washington.  In the paired case we clearly can.

You can get more details by referring to my text **Introductory Biostatistics for the Health Sciences: Modern Applications Including Bootstrap pp. 195-199.  Michael R. Chernick and Robert H. Friis Wiley (2003).**